An urn model with weighted objects and replacement
Consider the following game:
In an urn, there are $K$ balls, $x_0$ of them are blue and light (mass $m_0$), $x_1$ are blue and heavy ($m_1$), $x_2$ are red and light ($m_2$), the rest $x_3$ are red and heavy ($m_3$). Let's say $0< m_0\leq m_1$ and $0<m_2\leq m_3$.
Now we draw balls according to weight with probability
$$p_i(\mathbf{x}')=\frac{m_i x_i}{\sum_{i=0}^3{m_ix_i}},\quad \mathbf{x}'=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)$$
If the drawn ball is light, replace it with a heavy ball of identical color.
If it's heavy, replace it with two light balls of the same color and remove one of those $K+1$ balls uniformly (independent of weight).
After every move, the number of balls is still $K$, so there are 3 degrees of freedom specifying the urn's composition, let's say $x_1,x_2,x_3$ (and $x_0=K-x_1-x_2-x_3$).
We can repeat these moves, but once only balls of the same color are left, the game ends and this color wins. WLOG red balls should win, so let $\gamma(\mathbf{x})$ be the probability that red wins when beginning the game with $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ balls.
Question 1: Is there an explicit formula for $\gamma(\mathbf{x})$?
My idea: This game is a Markov chain on
$$\Delta_3=\{\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\{0,...,K\}^3: x_1+x_2+x_3\leq K\}$$
and $\gamma(\mathbf{x})$ the absorption probability for the set $R=\{\mathbf{x}\in \Delta_3: x_2+x_3=K\}$. Hence, there is a recurrence equation and $\gamma$ is the smallest positive solution of this recurrence given by:
$$\gamma(\mathbf{x})=p_0(\mathbf{x})\gamma(\mathbf{x}+e_1)+p_2(\mathbf{x})\gamma(\mathbf{x}-e_2+e_3)
+p_1(\mathbf{x})\frac{K-x_1-x_2-x_2+2}{K+1}\gamma(\mathbf{x}-e_1)+p_1(\mathbf{x})\frac{x_1-1}{K+1}\gamma(\mathbf{x}-2e_1)
+p_1(\mathbf{x})\frac{x_2}{K+1}\gamma(\mathbf{x}-e_1-e_2)+p_1(\mathbf{x})\frac{x_3}{K+1}\gamma(\mathbf{x}-e_1-e_3)
+p_3(\mathbf{x})\frac{K-x_1-x_2-x_3}{K+1}\gamma(\mathbf{x}+2e_2-e_3)+p_3(\mathbf{x})\frac{x_1}{K+1}\gamma(\mathbf{x}-e_1+2e_2-e_3)
+p_3(\mathbf{x})\frac{x_2+2}{K+1}\gamma(\mathbf{x}+e_2-e_3)+p_3(\mathbf{x})\frac{x_3-1}{K+1}\gamma(\mathbf{x}+2e_2-2e_3)$$
($e_i$ are unit vectors) with boundary conditions $\gamma(i,0,0)=0$ and $\gamma(0,i,K-i)=1$ for $0\leq i\leq K$.
Honestly, I'm at a loss how to treat this without numerical calculations. However, if $m_0=m_2$ and $m_1=m_3$ by symmetry $\gamma(0,i,0)=\frac{i}{K}$ and $\gamma(K-i,0,i)=\frac{i}{K}$
(much more interesting) Question 2: I did some numerical calculations and plotted the values of $\gamma_K(0,1,0)$ (starting with one red light ball and $K-1$ blue light balls, red wins) against $K$ and this seems to converge to a positive constant for $m_2> m_0, m_3> m_1$. But I can't prove this claim. How could one do this?
My idea: No idea, just some simple observations: Using a coupling argument, one can show that $\gamma_K(0,1,0)\rightarrow 0$ for $m_2\leq m_0, m_3\leq m_1$ by comparing it to the symmetric case ($\gamma_K(0,1,0)\leq \frac{1}{K}$). Similarly, for the interesting case $m_2> m_0, m_3> m_1$ one can show that $\gamma_K(0,\lfloor Kx\rfloor, 0)\rightarrow \gamma>0$ for any $x\in (0,1]$ because $\gamma_K(0,\lfloor Kx\rfloor,0)\geq \frac{\lfloor Kx\rfloor}{K}\rightarrow x$.
I'd be more than happy to receive some comments, hints, or references!

just a reference: https://people.bath.ac.uk/cdm37/urns.pdf are some good lecture notes on Pólya urns where you can have more complicated replacement rules
